# What does SPARQL "a" predicate do?

Tags: sparql

In this little snippet, what does the `a` in the second line do?

```
CONSTRUCT {  
  ?uri a skos:Concept ;  
         skos:prefLabel ?prefLabel ;
```

I'm sure this question already has an answer but I just couldn't find it. Sorry. (Whoever thought a single-character query language operator that's also an indefinite article in English was a good idea?)

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#abbrevRdfType

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The SPARQL keyword a is a shortcut for the common predicate rdf:type, giving the class of a resource.

From [here](https://www.w3.org/2009/Talks/0615-qbe/), found by googling 'SPARQL a keyword predicate'. Thanks to [Stanislav Kralin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7879193/stanislav-kralin).